# Adding a view to Slim Views Framework with composer

Tags: php, composer-php

I am writing a PHP template system for Slim, I have it working fine, but it is necessary to install the view file Ets.php in the correct existing location:

```
vendor/slim/views/Slim/Views/Ets.php
```

Whilst I can do it manually of course this defeats the object of composer. I was wondering if I can do it with https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/custom-installers.md but I am having trouble following the guide as it and others only really talk about installing outside of the `vendor` directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want the views to get installed in the same place?

Have a look into http://docs.slimframework.com/#Custom-Views

You just need to extend the `Slim\View`. An example taken from the docs

```
class CustomView extends \Slim\View
{
    public function render($template)
    {
        return 'The final rendered template';
    }
}
```

and integrate in to slim like

```
$app = new \Slim\Slim(array(
    'view' => new CustomView()
));
```

NB : Don't forget to do the autoload the classes required.

Comment: Thanks for this, new to composer and obviously not thinking logically.